Blazor Web Assembly (without authentication) and Identity Server 4
I already have Blazor Web assembly app which is made without authentication.
Now I want to add Identity Server 4, but all tutorials/documentations are showing step by step but when making new project they choose Blazor Web assembly with authentication, and I don't know what I should add so it works with me too.
My project is organized like: MyApp.Server, MyApp.Client and MyApp.Shared, and I have implementation of Identity Server in separated project.

Create and set up a new solution with the authentication set up.  Test it.  Then migrate your code to the new solution and configure whatever authorization you need for your pages.
